# Противоречия в статье википедии по MVC схеме

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, mvc

В википедии в [статье по MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) приведена простая схема, в которой отсутствует прямая связь между контроллером и представлением, также, помимо этого, в самое статье это упоминается неоднократно. Затем в разделе [Пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80) нам предлагается выдержка из фрейморвка yii, где явно видно присутствие прямой связи между пресдтавлением и контроллером. Получается, различные части статьи сами себе противоречят, или я как-то не так это всё понимаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы про то, что контроллер в итоге вызывает VIEW и передает туда Модель?
Так а по-другому как?

1. У тебя может быть 1 представление для нескольких моделей.
2. Модель - это набор данных по большей части. VIEW - это дизайн отображения данных. К примеру, в модели мы получаем структуру расходов в текущем месяце - мы можем представить ее как таблицу, как графики - но модель будет одна.

Comment: @Ale_x, но таким образом получается, отчасти нарушается изначальная концепция шаблона, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Вот неплохой сайтик по паттернам http://design-pattern.ru

Что именно нарушается?

Comment: @Ale_x, появляется связь между контроллером и представлением.

Comment: как бы да и как бы нет. Контроллер принимает запрос - и в нем нужно прописать, что надо выдать. Если продолжить мой ответ - есть две кнопки - Структура затрат в виде графика и кнопка Структура затрат в виде таблицы.
Так вот кнопки будут запрашивать разные контроллеры, но в них будет одна и та же модель, но представления разные. Контроллер - это как бы сборщик, управленец.

Answer (score 0):

1. yii - один из самых распространенных образцов плохой архитектуры. Чем больше я залезаю во внутренности кода, тем больше удивляюсь найденному там.
2. Зачем там пример, который демонстрирует работу yii вместо работы mvc - я не знаю.
3. Не нашел там прямой связи, кроме `<?= Html::encode($this->title) ?>`. Это опять ремарка в сторону архитектуры yii, эта штука должна передаваться с данными.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, как устроены все mvc фраймворки, но знаю точно, что 99% программистов, с которыми я обсуждал mvc, не понимают его и проповедуют лже-mvc. Это все к чему, если Вы сами ёще не определились, то руководствуйтесь wiki и первоисточником, ну и советами тех, кто проповедует то же направление.
И модель во вью не передается.